# Is there any way to not pass in the version number on llvm-16 when installed with apt on debian 12?

Tags: version, llvm

The main issue is that i have to pass in the version number every single time and it gets annoying. also many programs don't try to find the binary if it has a version. if any of you would be so kind as to help me with this i will be ever grateful.

Have to pass in version numbers. Didn't want to pass in version numbers

Comment: A symlink or two should do: `for a in $(grep /usr/bin/ /var/lib/dpkg/info/*llvm*.list) ; do ln -s $a $(echo $a | sed 's/-[0-9]+$//') ; done`